# python Importing local lib instead of builtin

Tags: python, python-3.x

I forked pandas in order to make a few changes. However, Python is importing the Anaconda builtin pandas instead of mine. Here's the directory structure ..

```
/Untitled2.ipynb > file I'm working on
/pandas/ > local Python code
```

In /Untitled2.ipynb, I have ..

```
from pandas import pandas
```

Then running

```
pandas?
```

returns

```
Type:        module
String form: <module 'pandas' from 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\
site-packages\\pandas\\__init__.py'>
File:        c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py
```

I want the module to import from /pandas/pandas instead. How can I do this?

Comment: Use a virtualenv.

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` or `pandas.py` in your `pandas` folder? What are you trying to import when you do `from pandas import pandas` ?

Comment: I have forked https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas. So there is an __init__.py here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/__init__.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert local pandas path to top of sys.path

```
sys.path.insert(0, r'/path_to_pandas')
```

Comment: this worked, I edited your answer to include the exact code that I used. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check sys.path and insure that '/' (or whereever pandas is installed) appears before 'c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages'.